# Creating a new variable for an outlier tag

Tags: r, outliers

So, i am doing an outlier detection for a given data set. This is done in R by the way.

With the function boxplot.stats(x)$out i get information for the variable that i am detecting outliers for. Right? I get the observation's value that is considered an outlier.

What i want to do is create a new column in the data set which could be binary and put a 1 for the observations that are outliers and 0 for the ones that are not outliers.

Example:

```
Var1   Var2
asd    111
dsa    15
ssa    10
aas    9
dad    10
dda    95
```

Lets say observation 1 and 6 is detected as an outlier:

```
Var1   Var2
asd    111
dda    95
```

When i use:

```
outlier <- boxplot.stats(Var2)$out
```

I only receive the value of the outliers - i get 111 and 95 in the console.
So.. After i have detected this outliers i want to do the following:

```
Var1   Var2   Outlier
asd    111    1
dsa    15     0
ssa    10     0
aas    9      0
dad    10     0
dda    95     1
```

It is probably really easy to do, but i don't know how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say your data.frame name is "data" and you have the values of outliers in "outlier"

then do this:

```
data$outlier = 0

data[which(data$Var2 %in% outlier),"outlier"] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
require(data.table)

data <- fread('Var1   Var2
asd    111
dsa    15
ssa    10
aas    9
dad    10
dda    95 ')

outliers <- fread('Var1   Var2
asd    111
dda    95 ')

data[, Outlier:= ifelse(paste(Var1, Var2) %in% paste(outliers$Var1, outliers$Var2), 1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min()` of the values in `boxplot.stats(Var2)$out` to compute the new variable via `ifelse()`.

Assume `data` is your dataframe:

```
data$outliers <- ifelse(data$Var2 < min(boxplot.stats(data$Var2)$out), 0, 1)
```

This way you don't have to save the values of the outliers in another redundant object first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an outlier in your vector like

```
outlier <- c(111,90)
```

You can use within function to subset the binary variable by using ifelse function

```
within(df,outlier <- ifelse(df$var1%in%outlier,1,0))

var1 var2 outlier
1  111  asd       1
2   10  csd       0
3   11  pud       0
4   12  dud       0
5   90  kud       1
```